# awk search column in one file to see if it matches any of the values in the second file

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to compare the first column of two (tab-delimited) files. If there is a match, print everything from file 1. E.g.:

file 1

```
  MOS   A   141282  141938
  LEE   A   11121   14597
  TOD   B   19237   20373
  LEA,DOT   A   1   1000
  MAS,ALE   C   24597   24599
```

file 2

```
LEE
LEA
ALE
EEL
```

Desired output:

```
  LEE   A   11121   14597
  LEA,DOT   A   1   1000
  MAS,ALE   C   24597   24599
```

Now, I can get it to find exact matches in column 1 using the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] =$1; next} $1 in a {print $0}' file2 file1
```

which gives:

```
LEE A   11121   14597
```

However, I'm a bit stumped as to how to make it pick up entries in column 1 where there is more than one word listed. I want to print every line that has the words I'm looking for, regardless of whether they ALSO have other (unimportant) words.  So how do I make it to recognize that

```
  LEA,DOT   A   1   1000
  MAS,ALE   C   24597   24599
```

also have the words I'm looking for, and print them in the output file?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a regex match in a loop, I think:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = $1; next}
             { for (k in a) if ($1 ~ a[k]) { print $0; break } }' file2 file1
```

Sample output:

```
  LEE   A   11121   14597
  LEA,DOT   A   1   1000
  MAS,ALE   C   24597   24599
```